# Using code for creating SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I like to do something like this in code:

```
string[] columns = new string[]{"col1, col2"};
var query = SELECT(columns).FROM("ANY_TABLE");
string strQuery = query.ToString();
```

and strQuery should contain now a sql query as string like:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM ANY_TABLE
```

I tried already to find something like this but I don't know any labels which I could use.
I know there is LINQ but I think it only works with EF and not sure whether it can output such a string.

THANKS

Comment: What have you tried?  If you wrote some code that throws an error, we can help with that, but we won't write it for you.

Comment: This is pretty easy to roll yourself, not sure you need another library

Comment: Also, the extension method syntax you have in your example does not make a whole lot of sense.  If you `SELECT` something you always need a `FROM`, in your example that could be omitted.  It makes no sense.

Comment: i think you are trying to pass column name and table name dynamically ,am i right @kinimod?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're actually asking here.  If you're just trying to build some kind of object or methods which accept strings that they use to build other strings then, well, yes you can do that.  What are you stuck on?

Comment: I like to have syntax checks in code. So that it is not possible something to do  SELECT(columns) without using FROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach could be:

```
            string[] columns = new string[] { "col1", "col2" };
        var query = @"SELECT ";
        foreach(var column in columns)
        {
            query += " " + column + ", ";
        }
        query = query.Substring(0, query.Length-2);
        query += @" FROM ANY_TABLE ";
        string strQuery = query.ToString();
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is not what I'm asking for. I'm searching for a framework/tool which supports also syntax checking at development time.